# regex for matching a word and numbers in same string

Tags: regex

I don't know regex and need to find the expressions to isolate strings that have the word "comp" plus any price (number)

any ideas?

```
249.00 | 259.00 | 279.00 | comp | 349.00 | //I need to return this as match
369.00 | 359.00 | 599.00 | //don't want to return this as match
299.00 | 499.00 | //don't want to return this as match
329.00 | //don't want to return this as match
comp | 269.00 | 269.00 | //I need to return this as match
179.00 | 239.00 | comp | //I need to return this as match
comp | //don't want to return this as match
89.00 | 89.00 | 89.00 | //no match
249.00 | //don't want to return this as match
comp | 249.00 | //I need to return this as matc
199.00 | comp | comp | //I need to return this as match
comp | comp | 99.00 | 99.00 | //I need to return this as match
comp | comp | comp | comp | comp | //I need to return this as match
```

Comment: i tried that but it gives me the strings that only have comp and i need the comp + numbers

Comment: /comp/gm should work

Comment: Why does `comp |` not match when `comp | comp | comp | comp | comp |` does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

**`(\bcomp\b.+([0-9]*[.]?[0-9]+))|(([0-9]*[.]?[0-9]+).+\bcomp\b)`**

`\bcomp\b` for boundary word `comp`.

`.+` for one to many characters.

`[0-9]*[.]?[0-9]+` for float number.

`|` for or condition. `number | comp` or `comp | number`

Answer (score 0):

Let try this

/\d?+comp\d?+/g

It will match all string "comp" with numbers. I think it right for you

Comment: @meebow: thanks. i changed to this (\d?).(comp\d?)  and it work but excluding the ones that start with "comp"